# Remove index from header and reindex data to start from 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame (`df`) that looks like:

```
3 IDENTIFIER   DEPARTMENT  
4      12233    MARKETING  
5      15389      FINANCE
6      12237    MARKETING
7      10610          OPS
8       6493          OPS
```

Is there a way to remove the index from the header and re-index from 0 please?

So the resulting data-frame looks like:

```
  IDENTIFIER   DEPARTMENT  
0      12233    MARKETING  
1      15389      FINANCE
2      12237    MARKETING
3      10610          OPS
4       6493          OPS
```

I have tried using without success:

```
 df.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check:

```
print (df.index.name)
None

print (df.columns.name)
3
```

And then set columns names to `None` with [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   IDENTIFIER DEPARTMENT
0       12233  MARKETING
1       15389    FINANCE
2       12237  MARKETING
3       10610        OPS
4        6493        OPS
```

Or:

```
df.columns.name = None
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   IDENTIFIER DEPARTMENT
0       12233  MARKETING
1       15389    FINANCE
2       12237  MARKETING
3       10610        OPS
4        6493        OPS
```

Or:

```
df.columns.name = None
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print (df)
   IDENTIFIER DEPARTMENT
0       12233  MARKETING
1       15389    FINANCE
2       12237  MARKETING
3       10610        OPS
4        6493        OPS
```

Answer (score 2):

agree with @jezrael

or you can set `inplace=True`

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Please dont change answer by my solution posted before.